# Bootstrap Button/Radio Responsive Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a strange problem with a bootstrap button styled radio input.

Basically everything is working when the screen is full size, but if I shrink it down to match any other media query, the buttons in my list stop working (still displayed but can't click).

Code is as follows for the buttons:

```
<div class="row">
<p class="lead text-center" id="viewText">View by...</p>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
<h3 class="text-center">Region</h3>
<div class="btn-group center-block" id="grpReg" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn btn-default btn-md btn-block text-center">
<input type="radio" name="optReg" value="AP" autocomplete="off"> Asia Pacific
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default btn-md btn-block">
<input type="radio" name="optReg" value="EU" autocomplete="off"> European Union
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default btn-md btn-block">
<input type="radio" name="optReg" value="US" autocomplete="off"> United States
</label>
</div>
</div>
**other code**
</div>
```

Comment: You should not include `input` elements inside `labels`. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#checkboxes-and-radios

Comment: I took that code straight from the bootstrap site. All of their JS based button stylings have the input inside the label. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you use default inputs.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVGVdm Working good here (default bootstrap + your code)

Comment: I refactored it using non-block buttons and it works. No idea why the block display would cause it to not function :/